# Storing configurable encrypted password of MongoDB User in Spring Boot

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, password-encryption

I have stored the password of **MongoDB** in `spring.data.mongodb.password` property in `application.yml` file in my spring boot project. I need to encrypt it so that it is not directly accessed by anyone. I do not intend to do any code changes for it but want to achieve it by some kind of spring boot configuration.

Comment: Please show us the code including things you have already tried. This way we can help you better.

Comment: There is no code for it. It is config file-based. In application.yml file, the property spring.data.mongodb.password has the password value.

Comment: I was referring to the encryption of the properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue got resolved. The problem was with the jasypt version. I was using jasypt-3.0.0 and it worked on 2.0.0. The full steps of configuring jasypt in the project can be found here :
https://medium.com/@mail2rajeevshukla/hiding-encrypting-database-password-in-the-application-properties-34d59fe104eb

I have passed the key in application.yml itself as the 3 mentioned methods were not working in my case.
jasypt:
  encryptor:
      password: secretkey

Answer (score 0):

The properties file should never be accessible by anyone (who uses of course the app)... Given that for granted, then I guess you mean to the other people working on your project, in that case I guess a possible solution would be to use BCEncryptor to encode a password and store it either in the properties file or on a side DB and then decrypt it at the launch of the application, through a configuration class or XML.

In any other case you could create a side user in MongoDB giving that use only the permissions you want.

But still, I wouldn't really see the use of it, because if someone have access to the backend of your application...

Comment: For decrypting the password I will have to use logic, right? I do not want to code.      Xml file will be pom file of spring boot?

Comment: Just a few lines of code. No, depending on your project standards and what is the rest of your project using. If there is no particular requirement, you should just use a @Configuration class to set up the decryption of the password... It’s literally just a function called decrypt(). Then of course there is the coding of the configuration file. But that depends on the rest of the project, I can’t really send you an example without a context.

Comment: I don't want to code anything but want to achieve it without code.I was trying to use jasypt dependency but getting some issues. --- Decryption of Properties failed,  make sure encryption/decryption passwords match
Caused by: org.jasypt.exceptions.EncryptionOperationNotPossibleException

Comment: Then I can't help you on that, sorry... Without code it's going to be pretty difficult, because it is not really much used.